# Improve results for a multi-label text classification problem using deep learning

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

I am using deep learning with keras for multi-label text classfication. However, the accuracy i am getting is only between 73-75. I think i am misjudging one of the parameters here. Is there a way to improve this? (by the way, the number of rows i have is 50858)

Here is the code i am using for building and fitting the model:

```
filter_length = 64
num_classes = 39
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 39, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(filter_length, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', strides=1))
model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

callbacks = [
    ReduceLROnPlateau(), 
    EarlyStopping(patience=4), 
    ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model-conv1d1.h5', save_best_only=True)
]

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    #class_weight=class_weight,
                    epochs=100,
                    batch_size=10,
                    validation_split=0.1,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give an answer without knowing the data and the results with different trials. What you have to do is tuning your hyperparameter, either automated or by hand.

Here are some experiments I would try:

- Increase the dimensionality of the embedding layers (allows it to contain more information), or use pre-trained word embeddings such as GloVe
- experiment with different parameters for the Conv1D layer
- Change the Conv1D layer to a recurrent one (e.g. LSTM, GRU), which normally work well with sequences
- Change the Global max pooling to max pooling
- Increase the batch size
- Add one extra layer to the network

Don't forget to keep track of your experiments: one great library for this is MLFlow. In this case, you might want to turn the model definition and compile into a function (e.g. `def build_model(**kwargs):` ) where your design decisions are controlled by the arguments. This can help you achieve a more readable and loggable code (in addition to working really well with automated hyperparameter tuning).

Finally, ensure your classes are balanced (and over/undersample otherwise) and randomly sorted when fed into the model. If not, consider if using e.g. AUC ROC instead of accuracy as a metric to track the model performance.